# Why didn't the Basilisk's bite destroy the Horcrux?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-chamber-of-secrets

At the end of the second film, Harry Potter gets bitten by the Basilisk in the Chamber of Secrets, before being healed by Fawkes's tears.

As the venom (from the fang) destroyed Riddle's book, why didn't it destroy first the Last Horcrux, within Harry?

Comment: Exact question on SFF: [Why Didn't the Basilisk Bite in Chamber of Secrets Destroy the Horcrux?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8659/21267)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JK Rowling has actually addressed this very subject, at Carnegie Hall in 2007:

> **Question**: When Harry was stabbed by a basilisk in the Chamber of Secrets,
>   since he was a Horcrux shouldn’t it have been destroyed then?
>
> **JK Rowling**: I have been asked that a lot. Harry was exceptionally fortunate
>   in that he had Fawkes. So before he could be destroyed without repair,
>   which is what is necessary to destroy a horcrux, he was mended.
>   However, I made sure that Fawkes wasn’t around the second time a
>   Horcrux got stabbed by a basilisk fang, so the poison did its work and
>   it was irreparable within a short period of time…. I established early
>   in the book, Hermione says that you destroy a Horcrux by using
>   something so powerful that there’s no remedy. But she does say there
>   is a remedy for basilisk poison but of course it has to be
>   administered immediately and when they stab the cup later – boy I’m
>   really blowing this for anyone who hasn’t finished the book – there’s
>   Fawkes, is my answer. And thank you for giving me a chance to say that
>   because people have argued that quite a lot.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like a cop-out to me. The fang destroyed the cup immediately just like the sword did to the locket, and snake. The truth is Rowling didnt plan Harry being a Horucrux when she wrote the second book.